# Postgresql "Cluster is not running" after running for a while

Tags: postgresql, azure-vm

I set up a postgresql db on azure VM, Ubuntu server 18.04.
but it goes down after running for a while without any other error message.

Here is what I got from `sudo systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service`

```
Feb 18 08:08:52 server crontab[17689]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
Feb 18 08:08:52 server crontab[17692]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
Feb 18 08:08:52 server crontab[17695]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
Feb 18 08:08:52 server crontab[17697]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
Feb 18 08:08:52 server crontab[17698]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
Feb 18 08:08:52 server crontab[17700]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
Feb 18 08:08:52 server crontab[17701]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
Feb 18 08:08:53 server postgresql@10-main[17704]: Cluster is not running.
Feb 18 08:08:53 server systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
Feb 18 08:08:53 server systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

`sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service` may temporarily resolve this problem, but may reoccur after a while.

Does anyone face the same issue?
Any advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, postgresql was killed by the oom killer.